# Clustering PostgreSQL clusters

Tags: postgresql, repmgr

This will be confusing for some due to poor terminology choices by the PostgreSQL folks, but please bear with me...

We have a need to be able to support multiple PostgreSQL (PG) clusters, and cluster them on multiple servers using, e.g. repmgr.  For example, to support both server availability and also PITR for each PG cluster.  A single PG cluster per server is too expensive in many cases, so we multi-tenant (small) customers on separate PG clusters, for data separation, recovery, etc., but also want to be able to support HA via replication/fail-over.

The closest analogy for a PG cluster is a SQL Server instance - each can host multiple DB's, has its own port, etc.  Like SQL Server, you can run multiple instances (PG clusters) on the same server, and set up replication for each.

Basic repmgr setup is no problem - that seems fairly clear in the single PG cluster model.  But, is there any recommended/supported approach to multiple PG clusters using repmgr?  I can kind of imagine faking repmgr into thinking each PG cluster is in effect a separate repmgr cluster (with separate repmgr.conf, connection info/port).  But, I'm not yet sure that will work.

I'd typically expect to fail-over all PG clusters on the same server - not one at a time.

I recognize this may not be the best idea in all cases, but am mostly exploring what's possible.  I have some alternatives, but this is closest to our current single-node model.

To clarify, I need to support many thousands of customers across many server clusters.  Ideally, each cluster uses the same repmgr DB (in the main PG cluster, e.g.), and essentially stands alone from the other server clusters.

Thanks...

Comment: I really want PostgreSQL to drop the term "cluster" :( . I use "instance" instead. Maybe you should edit to clarify accordingly. Anyway, it sounds like you're managing many single-tenant postgres instances. Consider automating this through tooling - Ansible, Puppet, etc - and containers - Docker, AWS, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, but I hope someone eventually posts a better answer, as I otherwise quite like repmgr.  In the end, it appears repmgr just isn't suitable for multiple PG clusters (instances), as there is an implied relationship between the repmgr cluster connection strings and the PG cluster (port).  Thus, you'd essentially have to create a separate repmgr environment (DB) for every clustered PG cluster/instance, losing a lot of the operational simplicity that repmgr brings to the table.

I will investigate a more generic solution using Corosync/Pacemaker/etc., as at least in that case, the virtual cluster IP handling is built-in to the solution, and doesn't require additional software/resources to pull off.

I'm sure I'm probably over-simplifying things, but it seems like repmgr was tantilizingly close to solving much of the problem, had it allowed the repmgr DB to be fully independent of the PG cluster and allow each repmgr cluster to specify its own connection info, not (only) the connection info for the repmgr DB itself.